# Javascript can not calculate days difference properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code

```js
function test() {
  const endDate = new Date("2023-04-28T23:00:00-0700")
  const today = new Date()

  endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

  // Convert to local date string
  const endDateString = endDate.toLocaleDateString()
  const todayString = today.toLocaleDateString()

  // Compare local date strings
  if (endDateString === todayString) {
    return 0
  }

  const timeDifference = endDate.getTime() - today.getTime()
  const daysLeft = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24))

  return daysLeft
}

console.log(test());
```

Today is 27th of April in London, UK, but when I see the daysLeft output it returns 2 days. I am not sure why this is the case

Answer (score 2):

2 is the expected output. Consider:

- `endDate` is initially defined with a timezone indicator of -7:00, while your location has a timezone of +1:00 (GMT + daylight saving). This means that `endDate` is 2023-04-29 07:00:00 +01:00 (in your local timezone). When in the US it is Friday late in the evening, it is Saturday morning in Western Europe.
- `today` is initially approximately 2023-04-29 17:30:00 +0100 (your local time).
- After removing the time parts from the **local** datetime, we are left with:

  ```
  newDate: 2023-04-29 00:00:00 +0100
  today: 2023-04-27 00:00:00 +0100
  ```

And indeed that gives a difference of 2 days.

So yes, Javascript **can** "calculate days difference properly".